# how to store away sequence variables with constraints in swift

Tags: swift

I wanted to create a "where_non_null" operation that works on any swift sequence - which is easy if you return an array, but obviously that is potentially bad performance wise - because you are forcing the entire sequence to resolve in memory - so I created the following that just goes line by line:

```swift
//
// this iterates through the underlying sequence, and returns only the values that are not null
//
public class Not_null_iterator<T> : IteratorProtocol
{
    public typealias Element = T
    private let next_function : () -> T?
    
    init<T_iterator: IteratorProtocol>( _ source: T_iterator  ) where T_iterator.Element == Optional<T>
    {
        var iterator = source
        next_function =
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if let next_value = iterator.next()
                {
                    if let not_null_value = next_value
                    {
                        return not_null_value
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
        
    public func next() -> T? {
        next_function()
    }
    
}

//
// a sequence wrapping an underlying sequence, that removes any nulls as we go through
//
public class Not_null_sequence<T > : Sequence
{
    private var iterator_creator : () -> Not_null_iterator<T>
    
    init<T_source_sequence : Sequence >( _ source : T_source_sequence ) where T_source_sequence.Element == Optional<T>
    {
        iterator_creator =
        {
            Not_null_iterator(source.makeIterator())
        }
    }
    
    public func makeIterator() -> Not_null_iterator<T>
    {
        iterator_creator()
    }
    
}


extension Sequence
{
    //
    // return only the not null values in the sequence without ever resolving more than one item in memory at one time and remove the optionality on the type
    //
    func where_not_null<T>() -> Not_null_sequence<T> where Element == Optional<T>
    {
        return Not_null_sequence( self)
    }
}


class Where_not_null_tests : XCTestCase
{
    public func test_where_not_null()
    {
        let source = [1, 2, 3, nil, 4]
        let checked : [Int] = Array(source.where_not_null())
        XCTAssertEqual([1,2,3,4],checked)
    }
}
```

which works great - however I had to define the next() and make_iterator() functions in the constructor, because I couldn't find any type safe way of putting the source into a class level variable.

Is there a way of doing that?

[and yes, I'm aware swift people prefer camel case]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way swift generics work can sometimes be very confusing (but has it's advantages). Instead of declaring that a variable *is* of a generic protocol (resp. a protocol with associated types), you instead declare another generic type which itself conforms to your protocol. Here's your iterator as an example (I have taken the liberty to clean up the code a bit):

```swift
public class Not_null_iterator<T, T_iterator> : IteratorProtocol where
    T_iterator: IteratorProtocol,
    T_iterator.Element == Optional<T>
{
    private var source: T_iterator
    
    init(_ source: T_iterator) {
        self.source = source
    }
    
    public func next() -> T? {
        while let next_value = source.next()
        {
            if let not_null_value = next_value
            {
                return not_null_value
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    
}
```

The non-null sequence works analogous:

```swift
public class Not_null_sequence<T, Source>: Sequence where
    Source: Sequence,
    Source.Element == Optional<T>
{
    private var source: Source
    
    init(_ source: Source) {
        self.source = source
    }
    
    public func makeIterator() -> Not_null_iterator<T, Source.Iterator> {
        Not_null_iterator(self.source.makeIterator())
    }
    
}
```

Using this `some IteratorProtocol` is just a nice way to let the compiler figure out the type. It is equivalent to saying `Not_null_iterator<T, Source.Iterator>`

As a (potentially) interesting side-note, to clean up the generic mess even more, you can nest the iterator class inside the `Not_null_sequence`:

```swift
public class Not_null_sequence<T, Source>: Sequence where
    Source: Sequence,
    Source.Element == Optional<T>
{
    private var source: Source
    
    init(_ source: Source) {
        self.source = source
    }
    
    public func makeIterator() -> Iterator{
        Iterator(self.source.makeIterator())
    }
    
    public class Iterator: IteratorProtocol {
        private var source: Source.Iterator
        
        init(_ source: Source.Iterator) {
            self.source = source
        }
        
        public func next() -> T? {
            while let next_value = source.next()
            {
                if let not_null_value = next_value
                {
                    return not_null_value
                }
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: awesome - thanks... and I like the where let - didn't know you could do that - I keep trying to do a ternary let and it doesn't let me, so I thought it only worked with ifs.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than just using one generic parameter, you'd need two generic parameters. You can't just constrain one generic parameter to say that it has to be some sequence with an element of some `Optional`. You need another generic parameter to say what the optional's type is:

```
class NotNilIterator<T: IteratorProtocol, U>: IteratorProtocol where T.Element == U? {
    typealias Element = U
    
    var iterator: T
    init(_ source: T) {
        iterator = source
    }
    
    func next() -> Element? {
        // I feel this is clearer what is going on
        while true {
            switch iterator.next() {
            case .some(.none):
                continue
            case .none:
                return nil
            case .some(.some(let element)):
                return element
            }
        }
    }
}

class NotNilSequence<T: Sequence, U> : Sequence where T.Element == U?
{
    let sequence: T
    
    init(_ source : T)
    {
        sequence = source
    }
    
    public func makeIterator() -> NotNilIterator<T.Iterator, U>
    {
        .init(sequence.makeIterator())
    }
}
```

`whereNotNil` would then be declared like this:

```
func whereNotNil<T>() -> NotNilSequence<Self, T> where Self.Element == T?
{
    return .init(self)
}
```

Note the use of self types. The first parameter is the type of the underlying sequence, the second is the non-optional type.

Note that this sort of "lazily computed sequence" is already built into Swift. To lazily filter out the nils, do:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, nil, 4]
let arrayWithoutNil = array.lazy.compactMap { $0 }
```

The downside is that the type names are quite long. `arrayWithoutNil` is of type

```
LazyMapSequence<LazyFilterSequence<LazyMapSequence<LazySequence<[Int?]>.Elements, Int?>>, Int>
```

But you *can* indeed get non-optional `Int`s out of it, so it does work.

Comment: thanks - the lazy and compact map I was unaware of.  (I'm still brand new to swift)